# PHP Parse certain Element HTML File

Tags: php, html, parsing, file-get-contents

how can I parse certain Elements from a HTML File via PHP
Thats my HTML File:

```
https://pastebin.com/raw/vVYqrCUd
```

I want to get the ,  and the  from every item in the HTML File.
Thats my current PHP Code:

```
$json_object= file_get_contents($url);
$json_decoded = json_decode($json_object);

preg_match_all('/<span class="(normal_price|market_listing_num_listings_qty|market_listing_item_name)">(.*)<\/span>/',$json_decoded->results_html, $sor);

foreach($sor[1] as $k => $v)
{
echo "Name" .$v[0]."<br/>";
echo "price" .$v[1]."<br/>";
echo "des" .$v[2]."<br/>";
}
```

Thanks a lot,
With best Regards
Maro

Comment: "_I want to get the , and the from every item_" The what, what and what?

Comment: I want to get the Name, quantity and Price from every item in the HTML File. These three infomations should be in one foreach for every item like in my example.